# Bug with dates, set wrong on or the other pair

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am quite new with VBa and i am facing a problem right now. I have in a Multipage, with 2 pages, a frame in each, inside each frame i have to Date picker for Initial date and Final date, named DTPicker1Li, DTPicker2LI, DTPicker3LI and DTPicker4LI. The form in whic they are is frmInserirImpLI.

for getting the values

```
 DInicioILI = frmInserirImpLI.DTPicker1LI.Value
 DFimILI = frmInserirImpLI.DTPicker2LI.Value
 DInicioLImp = frmInserirImpLI.DTPicker3LI.Value
 DFimLImp = frmInserirImpLI.DTPicker4LI.Value
```

for writing in excel cells i have

```
 Range("H" & linhaAEscreverLI) = DInicioILI
 Range("I" & linhaAEscreverLI) = DFimILI
 Range("O" & linhaAEscreverLI) = DInicioLImp
 Range("P" & linhaAEscreverLI) = DFimLImp
```

The problem is it only passes the correct dates for 2 of the cells.
or it write in columns H and I the correct dates and then in columns O and P appears: `00-01-1900`
or if the dates appears correctly in columns O and P it will appear in columns H and I: 
`12:00:00 AM`
what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick quesiton: Is this file for your personal use or will you be sending it across to other people as well?

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print DInicioILI, DFimILI, DInicioLImp, DFimLImp` to your code do you get 4 dates printed in the Immediate window?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is fixed, please validate an answer to mark the question as solved!

Comment: Plz validate answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just add formatting after setting the value :

```
Range("H" & linhaAEscreverLI) = DInicioILI
Range("H" & linhaAEscreverLI).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
```